# R: Converting nested list to dataframe and get names of list levels als factors

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a nested list:

```
list1 <- list("A"=c(1,1,1), "B"=c(2,2,2), "C"=c(3,3,3))
list2 <- list("F1" = list1, "F2" = list1)
```

and I would like to get the last level of the list (containing the vector) as a dataframe and I would like to get the levels of the list as factors:

```
  Level1 Level2 V1 V2 V3
1     F1      A  1  1  1
2     F1      B  2  2  2
3     F1      C  3  3  3
4     F2      A  1  1  1
5     F2      B  2  2  2
6     F2      C  3  3  3
```

The first part is nicely given by:

```
data.frame(matrix(unlist(list2), ncol=3, byrow=T))
```

However, I did not find a nice way to also get the list-level-names as factors in the same dataframe. Any ideas? :)

**Edit:** The procedure should work up to p dimensions.

Comment: `t(rbind.data.frame(list2))` gets you close - you only need to create variables from the rownames

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that the list names vary (they are values of parameters in a simulation) so I can't just use substr to cut out the factors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`melt` from "reshape2" has a method for `list`s. Perhaps it can be used in this case. Something like this:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(cbind(
  coln = sequence(rapply(list2, length)), 
  melt(list2)), L1 + L2 ~ coln, 
  value.var = "value")
#   L1 L2 1 2 3
# 1 F1  A 1 1 1
# 2 F1  B 2 2 2
# 3 F1  C 3 3 3
# 4 F2  A 1 1 1
# 5 F2  B 2 2 2
# 6 F2  C 3 3 3
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the hint to the reshape2 package.

Answer (score 2):

You can unlist just one level , than convert rownames to columns, and join the all in a  single data.frame:

```
xx <- do.call(rbind,unlist(list2,recursive = FALSE))
cbind.data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(rownames(xx),'.',fixed=TRUE))
                ,xx)

      1 2 1 2 3
F1.A F1 A 1 1 1
F1.B F1 B 2 2 2
F1.C F1 C 3 3 3
F2.A F2 A 1 1 1
F2.B F2 B 2 2 2
F2.C F2 C 3 3 3
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a nice solution, however I was looking for a procedure that works for p dimensions (Sorry for not being specific about that in the first place)

Answer (score 2):

With your own solution providing the values in columns `X1`, `X2` and `X3` already, you can do the following to get the first two columns `Level1` and `Level2` from the names of your two lists:

```
level1 <- as.factor(rep(names(list2), each = length(list1)))
level2 <- as.factor(rep(names(list1), times = length(list2)))
data.frame(Level1 = level1, Level2 = level2, matrix(unlist(list2), ncol=3, byrow=T))
```

which will result in this:

```
  Level1 Level2 X1 X2 X3
1     F1      A  1  1  1
2     F1      B  2  2  2
3     F1      C  3  3  3
4     F2      A  1  1  1
5     F2      B  2  2  2
6     F2      C  3  3  3
```

Comment: Thanks! It works very well, however, I was hoping for a procedure that works up to p dimensions (Sorry for not being specific about that in the first place)